# Sorting the terms of taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

How to set sort alphabetically in this view

[image: my view]

[image]

I badly I asked the question above. I did not write that I want to sort alphabetically by the "slownik". The first in the table. This field is a term taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Click here:

[image]

Then set the column to sortable, set the default sort order, and set the column to the default sort column:

[image]

Save settings and done.

Answer (score 0):

I did so

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Save settings and done.